# When i am calling JAVA Class from RPG Program i am facing error saying "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpg

i am developing the program writen by Scott Klement on "creating Spreedsheet with RPG using POI". i am able to create ".xlx" Spreedsheet but when calling the procedure which calls "XSSFWorkbook" am facing the below mentioned issues.

`enter code here`Message ID . . . . . . :   RNX0301       Severity . . . . . . . :   50
`enter code here`Message type . . . . . :   Diagnostic
`enter code here`Date sent  . . . . . . :                 Time sent  . . . . . . :

`enter code here`Message . . . . :   Java exception received when calling Java method.
`enter code here`Cause . . . . . :   RPG procedure XLCRTDEMO in program POI36/XLCRTDEMO
 `enter code here` received Java exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
`enter code here`  org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook (init" when
`enter code here`  calling method "
 `enter code here` "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook".

```
ADDENVVAR  ENVVAR(CLASSPATH1) +                                    
         VALUE('/home/Jar/poi-contrib-3.6-20091214.jar+ 
         :/home/Jar/commons-codec-1.10.jar+             
         :/home/Jar/commons-logging-1.1.jar+            
         :/home/Jar/curvesapi-1.03.jar+                 
         :/home/Jar/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.jar+ 
         :/home/Jar/junit-3.8.1.jar+                    
         :/home/Jar/log4j-1.2.13.jar+                   
         :/home/Jar/dom4j-1.6.1.jar+                    
         :/home/Jar/jsr173_1.0_api-RELEASE731.jar+      
         :/home/Jar/xbean-2.1.0.jar+                    
         :/home/Jar/poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar+         
         :/home/Jar/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar+ 
         :/home/Jar/poi-scratchpad-3.6-20091214.jar+    
         :/home/Jar/poi-examples-3.6-20091214.jar+ 
         :/home/Jar/xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar+   
         :/home/Jar/poi-3.6-20091214.jar') +            
         LEVEL(*JOB) +                                         
         REPLACE(*YES)
```

Comment: There are people who know how to help with this. I am not one of them. I strongly recommend using Python instead.

Answer (score 2):

It's CLASSPATH , not CLASSPATH1